# Bootstrap 3 not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use some basic bootstrap on my site but it's just not doing anything.
I have installed the 'bootstrap-sass' gem and written the css code in custom.css.sass but there is no any change in the site

This is the custom.css.scss file

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

/*universal */
html{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
section{
    overflow : auto;
}
textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}
.center{
    tent-align : center
}
.center h1{
    margin-bottom : 10px;
}

/* topography */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    line-height : 1;
}
h1 {
    font-size : 3em;
    letter-spacing : -2px;
    margin-bottom : 30px;
    text-align : center;
}
h2{
    font-size : 1.7em;
    letter-spacing : -1px;
    margin-bottom : 30px;
    text-align : center;
    font-weight : normal;
    color : #999;
}
p {
    font-size : 1.1em;
    line-height : 1.7em;
}

/* header */
#logo{
    float : left;
    margin-right : 10px;
    font-size : 1.7em;
    color : #fff;
    tex-transform : uppercase;
    letter-spacing : -1px;
    padding-top : 9px;
    font-weight : bold;
    line-height : 1;
}
#logo:hover {
    color : #fff;
    text-decoration : none;
}
```

This is the application.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track'       => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">   </script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
            <%= link_to "samples app", '#', id: "logo" %>
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li><%= link_to "Home", '#' %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Help", '#' %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the home.html file

```
<div class="center jumbotron">
  <h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>
  <h2>
    This is the home page for the
    <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
    sample application.
  </h2>
  <%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
</div>
<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIhif.png)

In `application.html` I've chanaged the (`stylesheet_link_tag 'application'` to `stylesheet_link_tag 'default'`) and (`javascript_include_tag 'application'` to `javascript_include_tag 'default'`) as it was sending an error as (Object doesnot support this method)

Comment: Any errors in your browser dev tools console?

Comment: Do you have any other css files? When you view the generated source in the browser and look up the css file, what do you get? It may be that `custom.css` is not included at all (depends on `default.css`).
Another issue may be that you named your file `.css` instead of `.scss`.

Comment: please post you application.css file

Answer (score 0):

Try Renaming `custom.css` to `custom.scss`

Comment: the file is actually named as custom.css.scss